# Transaction wrapped around Enterprise Data Library code + Entity Framework code

Tags: entity-framework, transactions, enterprise-library

Hey I have a unique and troubling situation.

I am working on a project where my team has used a mixture of Enterprise Data Library plus Entity Framework.  Obviously this probably not recommended but it is what I'm stuck with.  I would like to take a method written using Enterprise Data Library and also take a different method written using Entity Framework, and wrap both of these methods in a single transaction (without requiring Microsoft Distributed Transaction Service).  I'm hoping to minimize rewriting code and be able to wrap the two methods in a single transaction just as they are. Is this possible?  Thanks.

Using SQL Server 2008 and .NET 4.0

Comment: The answer is maybe but you haven't described the methods in enough detail to know.  Other factors that could affect the answer are what database and version as well as what .NET version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to mix EF and EntLib queries in the same `TransactionScope`, without using DTC.

Good news: it's possible. If you use exactly the same connection string for EntLib DAAB and EF DbContext, it will work, depending on the versions of EF, EntLib and SQL Server.

So what you have to do is:

1. check you have the right versions
2. get the version of your connection string changed by EF and use it instead of yours.

For 1, I have checked these combinations:

- SQL Server must be 2008 or older
- EntLib 4.1 + EF 5 doesn't work
- EntLib 5 + EF 5 works

For 2, to get the connection string changed by EF you have to debug the execution of code that uses an instance of a DbContext. Set a breakpoint and watch or inspect the DbContext `Database.Connection.ConnectionString` property. That's the EF version of your connection string. Use it for both EF and EntLib and you'll get rid of DTC.